# Detecting whether something is on STDIN

Tags: go, terminal, pipe, stdin

**Program** should be able to get input from `stdin` on terminal, as follows:

`echo foobar | program`

However, in the source below for **Program**, the `stdin` read blocks if the pipe is omitted:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    b := make([]byte, 1024)
    r := os.Stdin
    n, e := r.Read(b)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Err: %s\n", e)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Res: %s (%d)\n", b, n)

}
```

So how can **Program** detect *whether* something is being piped to it in this manner, and continue execution instead of blocking if not?

... and is it a good idea to do so?

Answer (score 1):

`os.Stdin` is treated like a file and has permissions. When `os.Stdin` is open, the perms are `0600`, when closed it's `0620`.

This code works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    stat, _ := os.Stdin.Stat()
    fmt.Printf("stdin mode: %v\n", stat.Mode().Perm())
    if stat.Mode().Perm() == 0600 {
        fmt.Printf("stdin open\n")
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("stdin close\n")

}
```

Comment: Is this a glitch or dependable behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible if you put the read in a goroutine and use select to do a non-blocking read from the channel in main, but you would then have a race condition where you could get different results depending on whether the data comes in quickly enough. What is the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: theres no larger problem, just for the sake of it.